# Istio manual sidecar injection gives an error

Tags: istio

I am trying to manually inject istio sidecar into an existing deployment according to the instructions here:

https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection

I am getting the following error, however:

```
$ istioctl kube-inject -f k8s/prod/deployment.yaml
Error: missing configuration map key "values" in "istio-sidecar-injector"
```

This error occurs to me even why I try different kinds with different yaml files. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? How can I add "values" to the configuration map?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your `istioctl` binary (`istioctl version`) versus istio installed on your cluster: if they differ, you may get such error message (or similar).

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. When I downgraded `istioctl` to the same version as on GKE, the error went away. Thanks!

Comment: how to check the istio version on GKE?

Comment: @Invictus When you view the details of a running Istio container on GKE, it displays the container's **image name**. For example, when I view an `istio-proxy` container, it shows that its image is `gke.gcr.io/istio/pilot:1.1.13-gke.0`. Thus, you can see that the Istio version on GKE is 1.1.13.